# In App Browser Not Closing

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, inappbrowser

I have a requirement to post data to an external URL. I tried using an in app browser, and here is my code :

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.action = "https://problematic.com/action/page.jsp";
form.method = 'POST';
//form.target = '_system';
form.target = 'NewFile';
form.style.display = 'none';

var inputCurrency = document.createElement('input');
inputCurrency.type = 'hidden';
inputCurrency.name = 'CURRENCYCODE';
inputCurrency.value = 'IDR';
form.appendChild(inputCurrency);

var inputCustEmail = document.createElement('input');
inputCustEmail.type = 'hidden';
inputCustEmail.name = 'CUSTEMAIL';
inputCustEmail.value = 'customer@gmail.com';
form.appendChild(inputCustEmail);

var inputReturnUrl = document.createElement('input');
inputReturnUrl.type = 'hidden';
inputReturnUrl.name = 'RETURN_URL';
inputReturnUrl.value = 'https://my.return.url.com/please-help-me';
form.appendChild(inputReturnUrl);

var submit = document.createElement('input');
submit.type = 'submit';
submit.id = 'submitProject';
form.appendChild(submit);

window.open("about:blank", "NewFile", "location=yes");
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

The data were posted to the URL, and the resulting URL showed clean as expected. But i can't close the browser and return to my app. There are no browser panel (like address input bar, stop, refresh, home, or exit). There is only the page. Back button also has no effect. When press back button, it says :

> 05-11 14:24:16.690: I/chromium(6938): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: cordova is not defined", source:  (1)

How can i get this code to work?

**EDIT :**
I also noticed that there was a browser window opened then close automatically a few seconds later. Right after that window closes another window open. This second window, is the problematic one. The one that do not respond to back button.

Comment: @IdanAdar sure in app browser is not MFP feature. But i do everything on MFP, and i am using cordova that built in the MFP. Do you have any thought to this problem? I'm kinda lost to what i have to do here

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/inappbrowser/inappbrowser.html#close

Comment: @IdanAdar how do i fire bla.close() after i tap back button?

Comment: Perhaps you can use WL.App.overrideBackButton: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.App.html?lang=en

Comment: @IdanAdar i added WL.App.overrideBackButton. Also added an alert in the function called by it. But the alert didn't show. I added it in the controller. I also found something weird. If i comment the window.open() and document.body.appendChild(form). The problematic window still appear. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that form.target doesn't work with InAppBrowser, therefore when you submit your form the webview will redirect to to the form's url. There are multiple ways you can send a **POST** request to an external endpoint.

1. You can user an adapter to act as a proxy
2. You can use WLResourceRequest, i.e., `var req = new WLResourceRequest('http://yourendpoint.com/', WLResourceRequest.POST); req.send({data:'your data object'})`;
3. Forms or any ajax function/library

That being said, if you want to use an InAppBrowser to submit a form and send a **POST** request to some endpoint you will need to do the following.

1. Create another html file for your app, i.e., **form.html**. This is the file where you will construct the form and populate with data passed in from the main view

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SubmitForm</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    loading screen, spinner, etc...
    <script>
      function sendFormData(data) {
        // create your form in the DOM, populate with the data object and submit
      }
    </script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

2. Open an the InAppBrowser from your main view or javascript file with the location set to **form.html**

```js
var win = window.open( "form.html", "_blank", "location=yes" );

win.addEventListener( "loadstop", function() {
    win.executeScript({ code: "sendFormData(" + JSON.stringify({form:'data',other:'more form data...'}) + ");" });
});
```

With **location=yes** it will have a close button so that the user can close the InAppBrowser and go back to the main view.

**PS:** Why is the iframe approach not working? The iframe behaves very similar to a browser window.